# HTML SaveXLSX Button Prevents saving data into a XLSX file from SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, html, blob, pug, slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid on a webpage and I am trying to add a button to call function CreateXLSX(). When I edit the code in Main.jade, I input:

```
input(type = 'button', value = 'SaveXLSX', onclick = 'createXLSX();')
```

The createXLSX() function is:

```
var inputData = getData();
var ws_name = "SheetJS";
var wb = Workbook(), ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
wb.Sheets[ws.name] = ws;
var result = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx',
                             bookSST:false, type: 'binary'});
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(result)],
       {type: "application/octet-stream"}), "Test.xlsx);
}
```

The parsing works fine when I execute createXLSX() right in the console window of FireBug. It creates a .xlsx file with all the data in the grid. But when I use the button, I get the error:

```
wb.Workbook is undefined
```

And when I refresh the page, the Open/Save console pops up as if the .xlsx file has been created despite the error. I need for the code, right when the button is click, to prompt the user like how it does when I'm not using the console to run the function.
Anyone knows why I am getting this error?

Comment: You are missing a double quote (ending "Test.xlsx...).  Did you also add FileSaver.js?  See the source of http://sheetjs.com/demos/writexlsx.html

Comment: @Nirk I did add FileSaver.js and I added another double quote after Test.xlsx. I figured that when I run the program without Firebug enabled, it runs correctly. Maybe Firebug thinks its a fatal error or something. Thanks for your feedback though!

Answer (score 1):

My code works fine without FireBug enabled. For some reason, FireBug thinks that there is a fatal error or something with wb.Workbook. But without FireBug, everything runs smoothly. If anyone knows why then I am open to listen to feedback.